# display all data in a row, if the user input is similar to a value

Tags: php, database, loops, mysqli, output

what am i doing wrong here! i want to display all data that is associated with a specific client id

EX user inputs "2"

all rows that has client_id "2" will be displayed

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit'] == "submit"){
   $username="xxx_admin";
   $password="xxx";
   $database="xxx_database";

//connect to mysql server
                $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

                                        //check if any connection error was encountered
                                        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                                            exit;
                                        }   
   $client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
   echo $client_id;
  $query = "select * from messages where client_id='$client_id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($query);
  $class_p = "timeling";
  $clid_p = "oldupdate";
  echo "<ol id=".$clid_p." class=".$class_p.">";echo $row->message;
                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                        {
                                                // set up a row for each record
                                                echo "<li>";
                                                echo $row->message;
                                                echo "<br>" . $row->date_post;
                                                echo "</li>";
                                        }

    echo "</ol>";

     $mysqli->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
.update_box
{
background-color:#D3E7F5; border-bottom:#ffffff solid 1px; padding-top:3px
}
a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#d02b55;
    }
    a:hover
    {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#d02b55;
    }
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}


    ol.timeline
    {list-style:none;font-size:1.2em;}ol.timeline li{ display:none;position:relative; }ol.timeline li:first-child{border-top:1px dashed #006699;}
    .delete_button
    {
    float:right; margin-right:10px; width:20px; height:20px
    }

    .cdelete_button
    {
    float:right; margin-right:10px; width:20px; height:20px
    }

    .feed_link
    {
    font-style:inherit; font-family:Georgia; font-size:13px;padding:10px; float:left; width:350px
    }
    .comment
    {
    color:#0000CC; text-decoration:underline
    }
    .delete_update
    {
    font-weight:bold;

    }
    .cdelete_update
    {
    font-weight:bold;

    }
    .post_box
    {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #006699;background-color:#F3F3F3;  width:499px;padding:.7em 0 2em 0;line-height:1.1em;

    }
    #fullbox
    {
    margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:6px; display:none;
    }
    .comment_box
    {
        display:none;margin-left:90px; padding:10px; background-color:#d3e7f5; width:300px;  height:50px;

    }
    .comment_load
    {
      margin-left:90px; padding:10px; background-color:#d3e7f5; width:300px; height:30px; font-size:15px; border-bottom:solid 1px #FFFFFF;

    }
    .text_area
    {
    width:290px;
    font-size:12px;
    height:30px;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form method="post" action="">

Search:</br>
<p>client id: <input type="text" name="client_id"/> </p></br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is all that I'm getting when i input a value and click submit

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

2
<ol id="oldupdate" class="timeling">
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
    // set up a row for each record
    echo "<li>";
    echo $row->message;
    echo "<br>" . $row->date_post;
    echo "</li>";
}
```

PHP Manual Reference Link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php